# Подсчитать количество элементов в ячейке dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется такой dataframe:

```
                        Interval
A1    A1-A2; A1-A1; A1-A3; A1-A1
A2    A2-A3; A2-A2; A2-A1; A2-A2
A3    A3-A2; A3-A2; A3-A1; A3-A3
A4                  A4-A3; A4-A4
A6                         A6-A4
A7                         A7-A8
A8           A8-A6; A8-A9; A8-A8
A9                  A9-A8; A9-A7
Name: x, dtype: object
```

По каждой группе надо посчитать количество пар

Вот мой кусочек кода:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Импортируй

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
require_cols = [1]
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', usecols=require_cols)
df_min_max = df.aggregate(['min', 'max'])
my_list = df["Data"].tolist()

# Меняем кол-во интервалов
bins = 9

# Сопоставляем данные с интервалами
interval = pd.cut(np.array(my_list), bins)
iv = df["Interval"] = pd.cut(df["Data"], bins,
                             labels=["A" + str(x) for x in range(1, bins + 1)])
# Разбиваем на группы

df["Interval"] = df["Interval"].astype(str)
df.loc[1:, "x"] = df.loc[1:, "Interval"] + "-" + df["Interval"].shift().loc[1:]

res = (df
       .dropna(subset=["x"])
       .groupby("Interval")
       ["x"]
       .apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep="; ")))

# Выводим результаты

print(my_list)
print(interval)
print(df_min_max)
print(iv)
print(res)
```

Желаемый результат:

```
                        Interval   пары
A1    A1-A2; A1-A1; A1-A3; A1-A1   4
A2    A2-A3; A2-A2; A2-A1; A2-A2   4
A3    A3-A2; A3-A2; A3-A1; A3-A3   4
A4                  A4-A3; A4-A4   2
A6                         A6-A4   1
A7                         A7-A8   1
A8           A8-A6; A8-A9; A8-A8   3
A9                  A9-A8; A9-A7   2
```

[файл](https://yadi.sk/i/6VU9YzHF_cuJLQ)

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При df

```
  Group                    Interval
0    A1  A1-A2; A1-A1; A1-A3; A1-A1
1    A2  A2-A3; A2-A2; A2-A1; A2-A2
2    A3  A3-A2; A3-A2; A3-A1; A3-A3
3    A4                A4-A3; A4-A4
4    A6                       A6-A4
5    A7                       A7-A8
6    A8         A8-A6; A8-A9; A8-A8
7    A9                A9-A8; A9-A7
```

делаем:

```
df["pairs"] = df["Interval"].str.split(";").apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

получаем df:

```
  Group                    Interval  pairs
0    A1  A1-A2; A1-A1; A1-A3; A1-A1      4
1    A2  A2-A3; A2-A2; A2-A1; A2-A2      4
2    A3  A3-A2; A3-A2; A3-A1; A3-A3      4
3    A4                A4-A3; A4-A4      2
4    A6                       A6-A4      1
5    A7                       A7-A8      1
6    A8         A8-A6; A8-A9; A8-A8      3
7    A9                A9-A8; A9-A7      2
```

**UPDATE**

Переписал весь код автора, чтобы получить желаемый результат:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Импортируй

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')
require_cols = [1]
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', usecols=require_cols)
df_min_max = df.aggregate(['min', 'max'])
my_list = df["Data"].tolist()

# Меняем кол-во интервалов
bins = 9

# Сопоставляем данные с интервалами
df["Interval"] = pd.cut(df["Data"], bins,
                             labels=["A" + str(x) for x in range(1, bins + 1)])
# Разбиваем на группы

df["Interval"] = df["Interval"].astype(str)
df.loc[1:, "Groups"] = df.loc[1:, "Interval"] + "-" + df["Interval"].shift().loc[1:]

res = (df
       .dropna(subset=["Groups"])
       .groupby("Interval")
       ["Groups"]
       .apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep="; "))).to_frame()

res["pairs"] = res["Groups"].str.split(";").apply(lambda x: len(x))

# Выводим результаты

print(my_list)
print(interval)
print(df_min_max)
print(res)
```

Теперь у вас в датафрейме `res` содержатся нужные вам данные:

```
                              Groups  pairs
Interval                                   
A1        A1-A2; A1-A1; A1-A3; A1-A1      4
A2        A2-A3; A2-A2; A2-A1; A2-A2      4
A3        A3-A2; A3-A2; A3-A1; A3-A3      4
A4                      A4-A3; A4-A4      2
A6                             A6-A4      1
A7                             A7-A8      1
A8               A8-A6; A8-A9; A8-A8      3
A9                      A9-A8; A9-A7      2
```

Comment: Перед #выводим результаты

Comment: ну так у вас же датафрейм называется res. Вот и пишите:  `res["pairs"] = res["Interval"].str.split(";").apply(lambda x: len(x))` . Кирилл, вам пора начинать понимать, что вы делаете.

Comment: Сделайте print(res) перед строкой с # Выводим результаты

Comment: Кирилл, добавьте ссылку на свой экселевский файл в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил........

Comment: Я обновил ответ